# How can I find specific object(data) in mutiple .RData by linux(ubuntu)?

Tags: r, linux, rdata

I would like to find specific object (data) in the mutiple .RData by linux (Ubuntu).

For example, I have some of .RData, and I want to find object name include "max" (so... max_1, max_2, ... in the .RData).

As I had no idea what the RData has specific object (data), I want to check multiple .RData whether .RData has a certain object (data).

Moreover, I want to do this in the linux (Ubuntu) environment.

Please let me know how to do this.

Thank you advanced.

Comment: Loop over all the object files, and use `nm "$file" | grep max`?

Comment: @Barmar Thank you for your reply. On the other hand, I want to search objects only within .RData files. What should I do?

Comment: What do you mean by .RData file? Are you talking about the R statistics package?

Comment: I thought you were asking about a section of Linux object files that are created when you compile programs in languages like C or C++.

Comment: It helps to tag your program more specifically, people who understand the application will find it.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. What I mean is that the data were saved as R format. For example code in R, save(object, "object.RData").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe try this in R console. This will give you all the available object whose names starts with "max".

```
files <- dir()
rdata_files <- files[grepl(".RData", files)]
rdata_files

for (fname in rdata_files) {
 obj_names <- load(fname)
 cat(fname, "\n")
 print(obj_names[grepl("^max", obj_names)])
}
```

Comment: he says he has multiple .RData files that he wants to search. So you need some kind of loop.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. As @Barmar said, I would like to search object in multiple .RData files. What should I do next.

Comment: It is not very clear what information you have and what exact outcome you desire.

Comment: for example, I have multiple .Rdata (A_1.RData, A_2.RData, A_3.RData...). And then I want to find object(data) which is start with "max" (max_ob1, max_ob2...). However, I didn't recognize which .RData includes a certain data (object) started with "max" because there are a lot of RData in my fold.

Comment: @RuiBarradas mistake. I have some RData files with object names starting with `asset`. Wasn't trying to be funny or offensive. I was just testing the code with what I have.

Comment: OK, just found it strange.